# Point Domain to Specific Folder In cPanel

Tags: wordpress, cpanel, shared-hosting

I've just installed WordPress on a shared hosting provider for the first time. The hosting service uses cPanel. When I go to **my-new-website.com**, the **cgi-bin** and **wp** folders are displayed. WordPress was installed in the **wp** folder. Currently, I have to go to **my-new-website.com/wp** to load the WordPress site. What do I need to do in cPanel, so that WordPress is loaded when someone visits **my-new-website.com**

My future plans are to have two additional websites that have their own instance of WordPress installed on my shared hosting account.

Answer (score 0):

**Move Files**

Move all your files in wp directory to root folder / `public_html`

**Change wp_options Table**

Change site_url and home in wp_options table from `my-new-website.com/wp` into `my-new-website.com`

ps: you may also need to update .htaccess file if in your .htaccess file rewrite base is `RewriteBase /wp/` , change it into `RewriteBase /`. By default .htaccess is hidden please check option to show hidden files in your file manager.

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks for your comments. What I would like to do is keep the wordpress files in the public_html/wp folder, but have WordPress load when the user visits the domain my-new-website.com. Currently, I have to go to my-new-website.com/wp to load WordPress. In the near future, I plan on creating a wp_2 and wp_3 folder inside the public_html folder that will contain 2 other instances of WordPress that point to two other domains.

Comment: I added the following to .htaccess:
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?my-new-website.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/wp/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /wp/$1
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?my-new-website.com$
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ wp/index.php [L] 
</IfModule>

I also changed siteurl and home values in wp_options from my-new-website.com/wp into my-new-website.com. So far, it seems to work properly. Is what I have done the proper way to fix this or will I run into other issues?

Comment: After reading your comment. For that kind of purpose I usually make (use) a fake domain as the main domain for cpanel account. Then easily i can adding some domains using add ons domain feature on cpanel. Every add ons domain will have their folder , redirect rule and ftp account. So i dont need to modify any code of a website